# Error while inserting one service into another

Tags: angular, typescript

I created one service - ContactService

```
type contactPredicate = (contact: Contact) => boolean;
type contactLike = Contact | string | SelectedContact;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  private selectedContactId: string = '';
  public selectedContactSubject: BehaviorSubject<contactLike>;

  public get SelectedContact(): contactLike {
    const contact: Contact = this.contactList.find((v) => v.Id === this.selectedContactId);

    return contact ? contact : null;
  }

  public set SelectedContact(value: contactLike) {
    this.selectedContactId = typeof value === 'string' ? value as string : value.Id;
    this.selectedContactSubject.next(this.findContact(this.selectedContactId));
  }

  constructor() {
    this.selectedContactSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Contact>(this.findContact(this.selectedContactId));
  }

}
```

When I'm inserting this service into another service-"FileService"

```
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {

  constructor(
    private httpServiceProvider: HttpServiceProvider,
    private userService: UserService,
    private contactService: ContactService) {
  }

  getFiles(fileType: string, contactType: ContactType, skip: number, pageSize: number, organisationId: string): Observable<any> {
    let myUserId = this.userService.userId;

    let selectedContact: SelectedContact;
    this.contactService.selectedContactSubject.subscribe(v => {
      selectedContact = (v as SelectedContact);
    });
    let selectedContactId = selectedContact.Id;
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

    params = params.set('category', fileType)
      .append('senderId', myUserId)
      .append('receiverId', selectedContactId)
      .append('Skip', skip.toString())
      .append('PageSize', pageSize.toString())
      .append('contactType', String(contactType))
      .append('organisationId', organisationId);

    return this.httpServiceProvider.httpGet(CONFIGURATION.GetFiles.url, params);
  }

}
```

SharedModule.ts

```
export function createConfig(): SignalRConfiguration
{
  const c = new SignalRConfiguration();
  c.hubName = CONFIGURATION.apiHub.name;
  c.url = CONFIGURATION.apiBaseUrl.server;

  return c;
}

const declarations: Array<any> = [
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SignalRModule.forRoot(createConfig),
    SharedModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule
  ],
  declarations: declarations,
  providers: [
    SignalRService,
    HeaderService,
    ContactService,
    MessageFlaggingService,
    DataShareService,
    ConfirmationService,
    ContactsMetaData,
    DateTimeUtility,
    FileService
  ],
  exports: declarations.concat([SharedModule])
})
export class DashboardSharedModule { }
```

AppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { DashboardSharedModule } from './dashboard/shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    DashboardSharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

DashboardSharedModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { MessageSectionComponent } from './message-section/message-section.component';
import { ConversationSectionComponent } from './conversation-section/conversation-section.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardSharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { DashboardRouteModule } from './dashboard.routing';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DashboardSharedModule,
    DashboardRouteModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    MessageSectionComponent,
    ConversationSectionComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Both the services exist in the same folder. I've also added both the services in my shared.module.ts But I'm getting following error -

ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FileService -> ContactService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FileService -> ContactService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ContactService!

PS - I've removed some code from here to make it understandable

Comment: Aside from the anti-pattern (shared module should be a *widget module*), show us `shared.module.ts`.

Comment: I also caution against returning unions from a function, for the ts compiler *will not* know exactly which type is returned at run-time and will require casting calls to such function screwing type inference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import DashboardSharedModule into AppModule and remove ContactService Provider from AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ContactService } from './dashboard/shared/Services/contact.service';
import { ContactService } from './dashboard/shared/Services/contact.service';
//DashboardSharedModule IMPORT STATEMENT

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    DashboardSharedModule//IMPORT HERE
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Architecture Best Practice

You also have a huge anti-pattern in your architecture, for a module should not have declarations/exports AND providers.

SharedModule should be a widget feature module:

> SharedModule is a conventional name for an NgModule with the
>   components, directives, and pipes that you use everywhere in your app.
>   **This module should consist entirely of declarations, most of them
>   exported.**
>
> The SharedModule may re-export other widget modules, such as
>   CommonModule, FormsModule, and NgModules with the UI controls that you
>   use most widely.
>
> **The SharedModule should not have providers for reasons explained
>   previously.** Nor should any of its imported or re-exported modules have
>   providers.
>
> Import the SharedModule in your feature modules, both those loaded
>   when the app starts and those you lazy load later.

CoreModule is a service feature module:

> CoreModule is a conventional name for an NgModule with providers for
>   the singleton services you load when the application starts.
>
> Import CoreModule in the root AppModule only. Never import CoreModule
>   in any other module.
>
> **Consider making CoreModule a pure services module with no
>   declarations.**

[Feature Module Types](https://angular.io/guide/module-types)

[SharedModule and CoreModule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-modules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them).

Comment: Restart your angular CLI

Comment: include your import statements for DashboardSharedModule

Answer (score 0):

Just import your `SharedModule` in your `app.module.ts` under `imports` array and it should not throw you this error .

Comment: Can you update the code with your app.module.ts  file? @PrashantYadav

Comment: Added both AppModule.ts and SharedModule.ts

Comment: @PrashantYadav updated my answer just include your shared module in your app.module.ts  , that goes via your class name `DashboardSharedModule`